# How do I get rid of the remaining enemy in the Bandit Slaughter quest?

Tags: borderlands-2

I was not able to finish instances of the [Bandit Slaughter](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Bandit_Slaughter) quest I was playing because an enemy is in a place where it can't be killed. It must be stuck as it appears to be not moving. The enemy is not visible to me, so I can't target a sniper rifle or rocket launcher at it. It is detected in the minimap though, and seems to be outside of the arena, as per this screenshot:

[image: Bandit Slaughter: Round 4]

If this enemy isn't killed I can't advance to the next wave.

If this happens, *aside* from save and quitting to reset the quest, is there another way to finish this quest? Is there a weapon or item that I can use to kill this enemy or make him come near me?

Answer (score 2):

Usually you can't.

The enemy on your screenshot is probably a Buzzard. Flying enemies, namely Buzzards, Surveyors and JET Loaders, can sometimes get stuck behind walls, outside map space reachable by player. In such cases your options are:

- move around to make the enemy move, and hope it flies back in via whatever hole in geometry in got out;
- move away to make it lose aggression, and then forget about it;
- try to kill it with homing weaponry;
- give up and restart quest.

Your particular case seems a sure **restart**, unfortunately. You can only pay more attention to Buzzard wave next time and make sure no one gets away.

*In BL1 Lance soldiers got stuck underground in the Secret Armory arena, but could be harmed with Transfusion grenades. In BL2, though, I can't remember a time when a JET Loader or a Surveyor came back from behind the wall.*

Comment: He's in the Bandit Slaughter arena: there are no flying enemies in this arena.

Comment: Goliaths jump very far though.

Comment: @KrzysztofJabłoński And the stalkers turn invisible. Why do you mention Goliaths?

Comment: Belated response to Gipphe: Bandit Slaughter arena does have Buzzards, and last I checked, they fly.

Answer (score 2):

I know this post is old, but for any newcomers, if you are playing as Gaige most times you can use Deathtrap to target and destroy stuck enemies. The chance of this working usually is better if you have the "The Stare" perk enebled. I had a problem in the Hyperion Circle of Slaughter with a stuck Serveyor and this took care of the it for me.